# Cannot resample my Dataframe properly

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a Dataframe where it has 30mins based data.

```
2013-02-21 00:30:00 693
2013-02-21 01:00:00 676
2013-02-21 01:30:00 649
2013-02-21 02:00:00 571
2013-02-21 02:30:00 546
2013-02-21 03:00:00 612
2013-02-21 03:30:00 594
...
2014-11-27 22:30:00 56869
2014-11-27 23:00:00 56121
2014-11-27 23:30:00 48772
2014-11-28 00:00:00 42980
```

I want to resample this dataframe following,

```
00:30:00    xxxxx
01:00:00    xxxxx
01:30:00    xxxxx
02:00:00    xxxxx
02:30:00    xxxxx
03:00:00    xxxxx
03:30:00    xxxxx
...
22:30:00    xxxxx
23:00:00    xxxxx
23:30:00    xxxxx
```

I could not implement it with following code.

```
df_sum_time = df_sum.resample('1D', how='sum')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resample bins the data into the frequency passed, so in this case it's going to group all the times from 1 day together.  It looks like you want to group by just the time part of the date, which would be done like this:

```
df.groupby(df.index.time).sum()
```